# How do I fix this Fibonacci Sequence?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I wrote this c++ Program that's suppose to do the Fibonacci Sequence. The problem once I pass 8 the sequence goes bad, like instead of the last number it messes up, I don't know how to explain it, just read the source code, but please help me, thanks very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sleep(3);
    cout << "Doing The Fibonacci Sequence"; sleep(5);
    cout << ""<<endl;
    for (int num=1; num <= 8; num++)
    {
        /*int number, lastnum;
          lastnum = num - 1;
          number = num + lastnum;
          cout << number<<endl;
        */
        for(int i=1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            //cout << num << "+" << i <<endl;
            int numb = num+i;
            int nun  = numb - 1;
            int c = nun + i;
            cout << nun << " + " << i << " = " << c <<endl;
            num ++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

/*The Output
  Doing The Fibonacci Sequence
1 + 1 = 2
3 + 2 = 5
5 + 3 = 8
7 + 4 = 11
9 + 5 = 14
11 + 6 = 17
13 + 7 = 20
15 + 8 = 23

*/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <unistd.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //sleep(3);
    int number;
    cout << "Doing The Fibonacci Sequence"; //sleep(5);
    cout << ""<<endl;
    cin>>number;
    int a=1;
    int b=1;

    for (int num=1; num < number-1; num++)
    {
        int c=a+b;
        cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c <<endl;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Doing The Fibonacci Sequence

8
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 5 = 8
5 + 8 = 13
8 + 13 = 21
```

check the code and see it might answer your question.

Comment: to get nth (says 'c') term, we will use and (n-2)th (says 'a') and (n-1)th (says 'b')terms.
So a=b ,b=c means now for next (n+1)th , we will use nth and (n-1)th terms..so for next iteration 'c' will be used as 'b'and 'b' will become 'a' to calculate new 'c'.we assign the previous variables (a and b) to calculate new value in next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your sequence is already bad on the second iteration, which should be 1 + 2 = 3. As for how to fix it... Fibonacci numbers are a classical example of recursion, so use that:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fib (int left, int right, int iterations) {
    if (iterations > 0) {
        cout << left << " + " << right << " = " << left + right << endl;
        fib (right, left + right, iterations - 1);
    }
}

int main () {
    cout << "Doing The Fibonacci Sequence" << endl;
    fib (1, 1, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

It works because mathematically speaking, each successive value in the sequence is defined in terms of its predecessors. The code simply follows this pattern. This technique (of defining something in terms of itself) is called 'recursion', and it's something a great many people have trouble with.

The first call (in main) sets up the initial values (1 and 1), and the number of iterations (8). The function itself prints those values plus their sum (easy so far, right?), and then starts the next iteration by calling *itself* with the appropriate values. The if-statement is necessary to ensure we stop after the correct number of iterations.

If you have trouble understanding this, simply follow the control flow (maybe write it out on a piece of paper): first we call fib(1,1,8), the next call will be fib(1,2,7), then fib (2,3,6), then fib (3,5,5) until we reach the value of zero for the last parameter. Hope this helps!

Comment: it works, but can you explain to me, how the function works  plz?